# Merge the [contactscontract] tag into the [android-contacts] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags [android-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contacts) and [contactscontract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contactscontract) point to the same idea: Android's contacts APIs.

I can't imagine a question tagged with one of them that shouldn't also be tagged with the other. Thus, I propose that the [contactscontract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contactscontract) tag be merged into the [android-contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-contacts) tag, and a synonym be created.

Comment: Which one should be merged in the other?

Comment: I'd merge `contactscontract` into `android-contacts`, as `android-contacts` is more popular, and more readable

Comment: when/how does a request get approved? does it require a certain number of votes?

Comment: bump... can we merge those tag already? how can this be done?

Comment: there are [10 questions which seem a bit ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcontactscontract%5D+-%5Bandroid%5D+-%5Bandroid-contacts%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0) whether they're about [tag:android] or not. If you can go through the 10 questions and remove the [tag:contactscontract] tag from those that are not about android and then ping me, I can merge the tags.

Comment: @BhargavRao ping